# Handle text input view movement with keyboard pan gesture in iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am developing an iOS app and
I have a messaging view where I want to handle this situation: 
-> I have a input view at the bottom of the view, that needs to be visible all the time except for some criteria where user is blocked/restricted to send message.
-> when the input view is focused, keyboard appears, I want to move the view along with keyboard frame.
-> I want keyboard to dismiss interactively with table view scrolling. With this being said, the view should respond to keyboard pan gesture and move along with as well
-> I tried using input accessory view but problem with that was when keyboard gets dismissed with table view scrolling, input view gets dismissed as well. 
-> I also tried using willShow/willHide/willChangeFrame observers but with this, response is not to the point and it doesn't respond to keyboard interactive dismissal.
Anybody got solution to this...
Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 3+:**
I have take a view into textview background and set the constraint of view **(leading, trailing, bottom, fixed height)**. Create a @IBOutlet for bottom constraint and manage that below code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var bottomConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    @IBOutlet var view_TextViewBg: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
            self,
            selector: #selector(keyboardDidShow(_:)),
            name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow,
            object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
            self,
            selector: #selector(keyboardDidHide(_:)),
            name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide,
            object: nil)

        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTap(sender:)))
        //  tap.delegate = self
        view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

    }
    func handleTap(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer? = nil) {
        //dissmiss your keyboard here
    }

    //MARK: Keyboard show

    func keyboardDidShow(_ notification: Notification) {
        let params = notification.userInfo
        let rect: CGRect? = (params?[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as AnyObject).cgRectValue
        bottomConstraint.constant = (rect?.size.height)!
    }

    //MARK: Keyboard hide

    func keyboardDidHide(_ notification: Notification) {
        bottomConstraint.constant = 0
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

[image]